# How to convert a bash string to date format?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash string `20220416124334` (the string is not epoch) and I want to convert it to date format so it should look like this: `2022/04/16 12:43:34`

I've tried:

```
[manjaro@manjaro ~]$ date -d '20220416124334' "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"
date: invalid date ‘20220416124334’
```

How should I do it correctly ?

Comment: `date -d '20220416 1243' "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" ` does work, fwiw. Space between date and time, and no seconds.

Comment: @Shawn this is the worst answer so far, you got rid of the `second` part from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect to use the `date` command, as you employ it, with a number that represents the number of seconds since the epoch. It seems your number is a formatted date `yyyymmddhhmiss`.

If you don't need to validate the string that represents a formatted date, then you can use `sed` to insert extra formatting characters:

```
echo '20220416124334' | sed -E 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/\1\/\2\/\3 \4:\5:\6/'
```

If you end up taking as input a number of seconds since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), then do it this way, keeping in mind that a number means different times in different time zones at different times of the year (eyeroll):

```
date -u -r 1650113014 "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"
```